# C# - What interfaces + operators must be implemented to get value comparison and equality on custom types?

Tags: c#, compare, equals, contains, equality

Let's say I have a custom type like

```
public class MyType
{
    public string name;
    public int count;

    public MyType(string n, int c)
    {
        name = n;
        count = c;
    }
}
```

in C# and want to have "intuitive" equality comparision for instances of that object. That is compare by value and not be reference. I am aware that the equality [operator ==](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) and [Object.Equals()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) default to reference equality. But I'd like two objects of `MyType` to be equal, if the contents match. The first step would be to override `Object.Equals()` and `operator==` with something like:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
   MyType t = obj as MyType;
   return (this.name == t.name) && (this.count == t.count);
}
```

However, there are also interfaces like:

- [`IEquatable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`IEqualityComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.iequalitycomparer(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`IComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.collections.icomparer(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`IComparer<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`IComparable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`IComparable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx)

which seem to be used in various scenarios involving comparison.

Do I have to implement all of these interfaces and the `operator==` and `operator!=` to make sure that any comparison involving `MyType` (including use in generic collections like e.g. in `List<T>.Contains()`) compares by value and not by reference? Or is there some other way I am missing? It seems to me that seven interfaces and two operators are quite a lot to have something simple like value comparison implemented.

Comment: Instead of `IComparer` interfaces, I think you were looking for `IComparable`. But that's really when you are required to pass your object into generic comparers that don't care about the data in the object, but need `<, >, ==`. I would recommend reading this MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I've added `IComparable` to the list.

Comment: Could the person who downvoted the question recently please explain the reason for that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The first step would be to override `Object.Equals()` and `operator==` with something like:

No, the first step is to override `object.Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`. You must **never** override one without overriding the other to correspond, or else your class is buggy if used as a key.

Let's look at your `Equals()`

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
   MyType t = obj as MyType;
   return (this.name == t.name) && (this.count == t.count);
}
```

There's a bug here because if `obj` is null or is not a `MyType` this will throw a `NullReferenceException`. Let's fix that:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
   MyType t = obj as MyType;
   return t != null && (name == t.name) && (count == t.count);
}
```

I'd also probably put the `count` comparison before the `name` as it is likely to give a faster out if it doesn't match, but then I don't know your use-cases so maybe there are a small number of very common `count` values in which case that doesn't hold. That's an optimisation matter though, let's fix the bug by giving you a corresponding `GetHashCode()`

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
   return (name?.GetHashCode() ?? 0) ^ count;
}
```

The minimum requirement is that if `a.Equals(b)` then it must be true that `a.GetHashCode() == b.GetHashCode()`. We also ideally want to spread the bits around as much as possible. We achieve the first (vital) part by basing our hash code on the properties that determine equality. The second part is more complicated, but in this case the relatively good quality of string's `GetHashCode()` means just xor-ing with the remaining integer value will probably be reasonably good. Search the site for more details (including why just xoring is often not a good idea in other cases).

Now, you want `==` semantics. It's a requirement that if you define `==` you must define `!=`, but we can easily define one in terms of the other.:

```
public static bool operator !=(MyType x, MyType y)
{
    return !(x == y);
}
```

Now once we've got `==` done `!=` will go through that. Of course we've already defined equality so we can start with using that:

```
public static bool operator ==(MyType x, MyType y)
{
    return x.Equals(y);
}
```

This is buggy though because while it handles `y` being null fine it throws if `x` is null. We need to consider that too:

```
public static bool operator ==(MyType x, MyType y)
{
    if (x == null)
    {
         return y == null;
    }
    return x.Equals(y);
}
```

Let's consider though that everything must be equal to itself (in fact you will be buggy if that doesn't hold). Since we have to consider the possibility of `x == null && y == null` let's think about that as an example of the case of `(object)x == (object)y`. This let's us skip the rest of the testing:

```
public static bool operator ==(MyType x, MyType y)
{
    if ((object)x == (object)y)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if ((object)x == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return x.Equals(y);
}
```

How much of a benefit this is depends on how likely comparing with self is (it can be more common as a side-effect of various things than you might guess) and how expensive the equality method is (in this case not much, but in a case with more fields to compare it could be considerable).

Okay, we've got the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` sorted and we've added a `==` and `!=` as you wanted them. What would be *nice* to have is `IEqutable<MyType>`. This offers a strongly-typed `Equals` that will be used when available by comparers within dictionaries, hash-sets, etc. So it's a nice to have. This will force us to implement `bool Equals(MyType other)` which will be much like the override we already did, but without the conversion:

```
public bool Equals(MyType other)
{
   return other != null && (name == other.name) && (count == other.count);
}
```

Bonus: Because of how overloading works our `==` is going to call into this slightly faster method instead of the override that does a cast. We've optimised `==`, and by extension `!=`, without even touching them!

Now if we implement this then we **have** to implement `GetHashCode()` which in turn means that we **have** to implement the `object.Equals()` override, but we've already done that. We're duplicating here though, so lets re-write the override to use the strongly typed form:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
  return Equals(obj as MyType);
}
```

All done. Putting it together:

```
public class MyType : IEquatable<MyType>
{
    public string name;
    public int count;

    public MyType(string n, int c)
    {
        name = n;
        count = c;
    }

    public bool Equals(MyType other)
    {
       return other != null && (name == other.name) && (count == other.count);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as MyType);

    public override int GetHashCode() => (name?.GetHashCode() ?? 0) ^ count;

    public static bool operator ==(MyType x, MyType y)
    {
        if ((object)x == (object)y)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if ((object)x == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return x.Equals(y);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(MyType x, MyType y) => !(x == y);
}
```

`IComparable<T>` and `IComparable` are used if you also want to be able to order your objects; to say one is less than or comes before the other. It isn't needed for equality.

`IEqualityComparer<T>` and `IEqualityComparer` are used to override all the above and define equality in some completely different way in *another* class. The classic example here is that sometimes we want "abc" to be equal to "ABC" and sometimes we don't, so we can't just depend on `==` or the `Equals()` methods of the types we've described above as they can only apply one rule. They are generally provided by *other* classes to the actual class being compared.

Let's say we sometimes want to ignore case in comparing `MyType` instances. Then we can do:

```
public class CaseInsensitiveMyTypeEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyType>
{
    public bool Equals(MyType x, MyType y)
    {
        if ((object)x == (object)y)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if ((object)x == null | (object)y == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return x.count == y.count && string.Equals(x.name, y.name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyType obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(obj.name) ^ obj.count;
    }
}
```

If you used this with say:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionar<MyType, int>(new CaseInsensitiveMyTypeEqualityComparer());
```

Then the dictionary would be case-insensitive for its keys. Note that since we defined equality based on case-insensitive comparison of the names we have to base the hash code on a case-insensitive hashing of it too.

If you don't use an `IEqualityComparer<MyType>` then the dictionary uses `EqualityComparer<MyType>.Default` which uses your more-efficient `IEquatable<MyType>` implementation since it can, and would have used the `object.Equals` override if you didn't have that.

You might guess that `IEqualityComparer<T>` is relatively less-used than just using the equality defined by a class itself. Also if someone does need it, that person might not be you; one of the great things about it is that we can define them for other people's classes. Still, it's not a concern for your design of your class itself.

Answer (score 2):

You don't *need* to implement those interfaces to be able to implement the equality operators. Just override them as desired for the type.

But if you do, you *must* override `Equals(object)` **and** `GetHashCode()` to ensure proper behavior.  You *should* implement `IEquatable<T>` because... might as well.

Likewise, for comparisons, override the operators as needed. There's no required interface for them. But if you do, again you *should* implement `IComparable<T>` in a manner consistent with the behavior of the operators.

You only really need implementations if `IEqualityComparer` or `IComparer` if you need to change the way your objects are compared *after* it has been implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You should just need `IEquatable<T>`, as well as the two operators.  As for the others:

`IEqualityComparer` and `IEqualityComparer<T>` are used if you want to make another object that's able to determine equality of other objects.

`IComparer` and `IComparer<T>` are used if you want to be able to sort your items (so ability to determine if one is greater than an other, not necessarily the same as equality).

Edit:

Also as Jeff mentions, if you override `Equals` you should also override `GetHashCode()`.

Comment: The Comparer interfaces can be used if you want a special Equatable/Comparable behaviour for a special case that you do not want to be the default equal/compare logic of the class